# MVC 5 multiple file upload uploads same file several times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httprequest, multifile-uploader

I have built a website using asp.net 4.5 and MVC 5.
In one of my views I want to upload multiple files.
With my code below, the first fileis collected and saved, but it is saved as many times as the number of files I try to upload.

**For example:**
I choose the files *pic1.jpg* and *pic2.jpg* with the file uploader. This results in the file *pic1.jpg* being saved twice.

While debugging I see that the `Request.Files[file];` code returns the same file each time. It seems that I get the same file uploader twice, and that only the first file is selected.

How do I alter my code to fetch all files selected via the uploader?

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel product)
        {
            ...

            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var hpf = Request.Files[file];
                if (hpf != null && hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                }
            }

            ...

            return RedirectToAction<ProductController>(x => x.Index());
        }
```

**View**

```
@model EVRY.OrderCapture.Administration.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
<h2>@Resources.Resources.Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        ...

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fileUpload" class="control-label col-md-2">Filename:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="files" id="fileUpload" multiple />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Resources.Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to this myself.
I had to select on index instead of name.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var hpf = Request.Files[i];
            if (hpf != null && hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
            }
        }
```